# An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I was trying to deploy my mern project my always i got this error

please help me to find out this issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVacD.png)

Comment: Please read the error and the Heroku documentation, then read the Help section about asking questions.

Comment: It would be best to list the steps you took to get this error and edit the question to make it make more sense. Looks like you have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I found two web pages that should help you in debugging your code here:

- [Causes of Heroku H10 App Crashed Error and How to Solve Them](https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl)
- [Heroku Error Code H10](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed)

The first is more detailed and the second links to an anchor on a list of error codes. If you're using Heroku, it's worth bookmarking that entire page. I'm interested to know what your specific issue turns out to be.